# How to swap order of html objects being displayed without changing the template?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a badge in my `span` that I only want to appear if `case 3` in my `getLatestSystemMessage` function is selected. My code is working fine except the badge is appearing on the wrong message because angular is reading the `span` first then the `{{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}` therefore the badge that is showing is showing on the next message rather than the current message. How can I overcome this in the right way? I need the badge to appear before the latest system message

Here is my component.html

```
<p class="mb-0">
     <span 
     class="badge badge-pill badge-success d-none" 
     [class.d-inline]="isAcceptedOffer">Accepted
     </span>
     <strong> {{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong>
</p>
```

and here is my component.ts

```
getLatestSystemMessage(thread: Thread): string {
        const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);

        const isUserOwner = thread.project.user.id === this.user.id;

        let content = '';

        this.isAcceptedOffer = false;

        if (message) {
            switch (message.type) {
                case 1:
                    if (<any>message.content > 0) {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered you $${message.content}` :
                            `You offered $${message.content}`;
                    } else {
                        content = isUserOwner ?
                            `Offered to translate for free` :
                            `You offered to translate for free`;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        'Cancelled offer' :
                        'You cancelled your offer';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.isAcceptedOffer = true;
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        `Offered you $${message.content}`:
                        `You offered $${message.content}`;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    content = isUserOwner ?
                        "You accepted another translator's offer" :
                        "Accepted another translator's offer";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cant swap `<span>` and `<strong>` elements in template to get desired order?

Comment: @AmirArbabian Yes I want the <span> to appear before the <strong>

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS Order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) within a css class and then activate it programmatically with `[ngClass]` when your condition is satisfied.

This way if `case 3` occurs, apply the class to all the elements whose order has to be changed. You can achieve this with just CSS, without altering the template.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to change the template. Here's my suggestion:

```html
<p class="mb-0">
     <span 
     class="badge badge-pill badge-success d-none" 
     [class.d-inline]="isAcceptedOffer(thread)">Accepted
     </span>
     <strong> {{getLatestSystemMessage(thread)}}</strong>
</p>
```

```js
isAcceptedOffer(thread: Thread): boolean {
  const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);
  return (message?.type === 3);
}

getLatestSystemMessage(thread: Thread): string {
  const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);

  const isUserOwner = thread.project.user.id === this.user.id;

  let content = '';

  if (message) {
    switch (message.type) {
      case 1:
        if (<any>message.content > 0) {
          content = isUserOwner ?
            `Offered you $${message.content}` :
            `You offered $${message.content}`;
        } else {
          content = isUserOwner ?
            `Offered to translate for free` :
            `You offered to translate for free`;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        content = isUserOwner ?
          'Cancelled offer' :
          'You cancelled your offer';
        break;
      case 3:
        this.isAcceptedOffer = true;
        content = isUserOwner ?
          `Offered you $${message.content}`:
          `You offered $${message.content}`;
        break;
      case 4:
        content = isUserOwner ?
          "You accepted another translator's offer" :
          "Accepted another translator's offer";
        break;
    }
  }

  return content;
}
```

If this cannot be done, I would probably go with Francesco's solution above.

Comment: this could work if I can add 2 functions to `[class.d-inline]="isAcceptedOffer(thread)"` as I also need to add `isAcceptedOffer` into it, is it possible to do that? I tried using &&  but it won't work

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. I changed `isAcceptedOffer` from a class property into a method in order to do this. If you want to retain the class property in addition to the method, one of them will have to be renamed. But I'm not entirely sure why you would want that. If this is used inside an `*ngFor`, the class property would then always contain the last thread processed.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't see that. I am getting `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '(thread: Thread) =>  boolean'` error

Comment: That's probably because you have `isAcceptedOffer` in your template instead of `isAcceptedOffer(thread)`. The function returns a boolean.

Comment: So sorry, I am pretty new to javascript, I am seeing this error `error TS1005: ':' expected.` in the `return (message?.type === 3);` line any idea how to fix this?

Comment: My guess is you forgot to add a `;` to the line above.

Comment: If this helped you, feel free to mark it as a solution.